# how to show the dynamic results with filter in the final report (.xlsx file)

Tags: sas, report

I am working on a report (.xlsx file).
the data has 3 columns for sales (sale1, sale2 and sale3).
In the final output (.xlsx file), I like to show:

1. the difference of the grand total between columns, i.e. -36 (=1008-1044) in column sale3, etc  please see the 1st picture
2. I like to see the the final report filtered (with filter load='Y') please see the 2nd picture  -
   the grand total for sale3 is 848 (860 for sale2, 871 for sale1), the column diff will be -12, and column %change will be (1.40%), the last row will be -11 (=848-860) and -11 (=860-871) for difference of the grand totals.

   ```
    data sales;
    input area load $ prod : $ sale1 sale2 sale3;
     diff=sale3-sale2;
    datalines;
    1 Y p1   109 117 138 
    1 N p1   23  29  20 
    1 Y p2   78  70  68
    1 N p2   63  19  22 
    2 Y p1   49  36  32 
    2 N p1   50  39  44  
    2 Y p3   138 157 158 
    2 N p3   110 126 107 
    3 Y p2   251 267 259  
    3 N p2   182 184 160 
    ;
    run;

    ods excel close;
    ods excel file="/C:/data/t1.xlsx"
      options (sheet_name="tab1" frozen_headers='3' frozen_rowheaders='2'       
               embedded_footnotes='yes' autofilter='1-8'); 
    proc report data=sales  nocenter;    
     column area load prod sale1 sale2 sale3 diff change;
     define area -- diff/ display; 
     define sale1-- diff / analysis sum format=comma12. style(column)= 
            [cellwidth=.5in];
     define change / computed format=percent8.2 '% change' style(column)= 
            [cellwidth=.8in];

    compute change;
     change = diff.sum/sale2.sum;
      if change >= 0.1 then call define ("change",'STYLE','STYLE=[color=red 
          fontweight=bold]');
      if change <= -0.1 then call define ("change",'STYLE','STYLE=[color=blue 
          fontweight=bold]');
    endcomp;

    rbreak after / summarize style=[background=lightblue font_weight=bold];
    run;
    ods excel close;
   ```

and the 1st picture shows report(no filter applied) looks like:
[image]

and the 2nd picture shows (filter applied) - this is what I want to see in the report [image]

Comment: The `ODS EXCEL` destination has no feature or option for preselecting the autofilters.  Autofilter item selection would involve VBA code or 'hacking' into the.xlsx flie

Comment: does this mean SAS cannot do the auto-filters?

Comment: `ODS EXCEL` can output tabled data with autofiltering enabled.  You can't specify the initial items selected (I.e. a filter applied)

Comment: Directly via SAS, no. But it's fairly trivial to do it via VBS and then call that script from SAS or something along those lines. Did you also ask this on communities.sas.com recently? Someone did and I can't recall what the official answer was but it's similar most likely.

Comment: i did not ask this question in any other place.  BTW, can I do the last row (-9 in column sale2, and -36 in column sale3) - that is, difference between the grand totals?

Answer (score 1):

The report total line can be made filter aware by replacing the hard sum computed by `REPORT` with a formula delivered to the cell via a call define style that sets the tagattr to an Excel formula.

The Excel function `SUBTOTAL(9,range)` is filter aware, and code `9` means compute the SUM.  Excel `INDIRECT` is used to compute the column cell range above the total row.

Example:

```
proc report data=sales  nocenter;
  column area load prod sale1 sale2 sale3 diff change;
  define area -- diff/ display;
  define sale1-- diff / analysis sum format=comma12. style(column)= [cellwidth=.5in];
  define change / computed format=percent8.2 '% change' style(column)= [cellwidth=.8in];

  compute change;
    change = diff.sum/sale2.sum;
    if change >=  0.1 then call define ("change",'STYLE','STYLE=[color=red fontweight=bold]');
    if change <= -0.1 then call define ("change",'STYLE','STYLE=[color=blue fontweight=bold]');
  endcomp;

  * inject Excel formula into summary cell;
  compute after;
    call define ('sale1.sum', 'style', "style=[tagattr='formula:=SUBTOTAL(9,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(ADDRESS(2,COLUMN()),"":"",ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))))']");
    call define ('sale2.sum', 'style', "style=[tagattr='formula:=SUBTOTAL(9,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(ADDRESS(2,COLUMN()),"":"",ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))))']");
    call define ('sale3.sum', 'style', "style=[tagattr='formula:=SUBTOTAL(9,INDIRECT(CONCATENATE(ADDRESS(2,COLUMN()),"":"",ADDRESS(ROW()-1,COLUMN()))))']");
  endcomp;

  rbreak after / summarize style=[background=lightblue font_weight=bold];

run;
```

As stated in the comments, the filter selections default to all values in column and you can not specify a preselection.

Not sure how to adding text/formula to specific cells outside a procedures output, but not likely easy.

Comment: Hi Richard, I added the summary (summation) in the first row [link](http://example.com) _italic_ **bold** `rbreak before / summarize style=[background=lightblue font_weight=bold];`  but once I tried to filter a column, the summation numbers had not change, they are still the totals. just wonder what should I do to list the summary in the first row correctly, thanks!

Comment: Jeff rather than extend this question, create a new question, referring back to this one, then state the issue there and show how you filter and what changes you expect to see

Comment: i cannot create a new question, and the message shows 'You have reached your question limit'. I used to asked question about prxmatch(), then i got some comments that I should not use that function, and soon after my account was restricted.